# what is 'mid-year estimate' in following chart?

Tags: macroeconomics, statistics, population-economics

If it is mid-year population then, why it is so less in comparison to 'total population'

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting, around 1000 times difference, is there any further information apart from the Table by the way?

Comment: @BeautifulMindset SOURCE: unstats.un.org as on 5-12-2016, mentioned in one the bottom side of the image

Comment: sorry, I still not yet fully understood why it is much less like that, but there should be something like the mid-year numbers should be multiplied by 1000 from my humble opinion.